# Getting the facebook-user-id of the like-button presser (facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK and fbml like-buttons. Using the 'edge.create' callback I know when someone has liked an url. Is it possible to get the facebook-user-id as well? Without them having to log into my App/Domain with FB Connect

I would like to double-store likes for internal statistics (since it's hard to get very fine grain domain statistics via facebook.com/insights)

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is not available to developers through any of the facebook API's. You might want to store the uid's locally when the user clicks a like button.

Hope that helps. 
-Roozbeh

Comment: Roozbeh15: Do you mean using FB Connect on the site first (to get their uid) and then store that uid when they click a like button? (that's what I'm leaning towards)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not possible to get a users id simply from them clicking on a like button.

I'm not sure why you would even need a users id to simply help you track like button clicks, if you need some sort of unique identifier try using sessions or a cookie.